# AttributeError: 'numpy.bool_' object has no attribute 'isin'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe that looks a bit like this:

```
cancelled | offer
----------|------
N         | 123 
N         | 456 
y         | 789
```

I'm trying to use an if statement to flag whether there are any cancelled offers (i.e. ones marked "Y" or "y") in the dataframe. This is the code I have so far:

```
if df["cancelled"].any().isin(["Y","y"]):
    print("WARNING - Cancelled offers included!")
else:
     print("OK - No cancelled offers are included.")
```

However, when I run this I get the following error:

```
 AttributeError: 'numpy.bool_' object has no attribute 'isin'
```

Obviously the *isin* function isn't compatible with the rest of my code, but in this case, what would be the proper method of getting the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant `df["cancelled"].isin(["Y","y"]).any()`:

```
if df["cancelled"].isin(["Y","y"]).any():
    print("WARNING - Cancelled offers included!")
else:
     print("OK - No cancelled offers are included.")
```

`df["cancelled"].isin(["Y","y"])` returns a Series, `df["cancelled"].isin(["Y","y"]).any()` converts the boolean Series into a single boolean.